# How to automatically login to Jenkins on Active Directory?

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins

I have an Active Directory plugin installed that allows logging in to Jenkins portal with my directory credentials by typing them in on the Login page.

But is there a way to automatically log in users if they are on a domain-joined machine? (Obviously, given the browser is configured to allow providing credentials to the site.)

Comment: Does https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Kerberos+SSO+Plugin help?

Comment: Thank you, that's a good start! The plugin wiki mentions that they haven't heard of a successful Windows installation/configuration. But I kept looking and [found a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/ywCwlY569dI/J351N6JjXagJ) by a guy who actually developed a separate plugin that works on Windows. I'll dig into that and update this question if that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a thread on Jenkins Dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/ywCwlY569dI/J351N6JjXagJ) in which a guy mentions that he developed an SSO plugin that worked for him on Windows. He posted it on GitHub under name [NegotiateSSO](https://github.com/FarmGeek4Life/NegotiateSSO).

First you need to build it to get the hpi file. (Clone the project to your machine, cd into the directory and run `mvn` (Maven) in it).

The problem is that when I tried to install it, it broke my Jenkins configuration section/page. There's an exception happening inside the plugin that breaks the entire page.

So it didn't work for me, but hopefully [it will get fixed](https://github.com/FarmGeek4Life/NegotiateSSO/issues/1) at some point and we'll be able to use it.